# Fullcalendar slotDuration solid / dotted separator on hour

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar with Scheduler and I have set the slotDuration to 15 minutes. But, this causes a solid grid separator on the hour AND half-hour. With a dotted separator on the quarter hour.

In the old version of Fullcalendar, I had the solid separator ONLY on the hour, with dotted separators on the quarter and half hours.

How do I set the code to have dotted on the quarter and half hours with solid on the hour?

Comment: I would guess it's controlled either by some CSS or JavaScript. Have you tried inspecting the element to see how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
tr[data-time="06:15:00"] > td:not(:first-child)
{
  border-top: 1px dotted green;
}
```

Please check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zrLm0kew/

You would have to add css for all the hours (x:15 x:30). Not very elegant. I will try to come up with the better idea.